# NDK Code Coverage

Tags: android, android-ndk, code-coverage

Does anybody enabled code coverage NDK build on Android?

by using cmake with the comments from this link  [code coverage for native code using Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48033153/code-coverage-for-native-code-using-android-ndk)

I ended up with the same error:
`set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} --coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} --coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")`

so I'm creating a new thread for asking this issue.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48033153/code-coverage-for-native-code-using-android-ndk

Answer (score 0):

The "same error" from the other thread:

> [3/3] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/project/debug/obj/armeabi/libscanhwl_camif.so
>     FAILED: : && /home/user/tools/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv5te-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=/home/user/tools/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/user/tools/android-ndk-r14b/sysroot -fPIC -isystem /home/user/tools/android-ndk-r14b/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -D__ANDROID_API__=19 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS  -fexceptions -frtti --coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a --sysroot /home/user/tools/android-ndk-r14b/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libscanhwl_camif.so -o  -latomic -lm "/home/user/tools/android-ndk-r14b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/libgnustl_static.a" && :
>     out/stage2/soong/ndk/sysroot/usr/include/string.h:348: error: undefined reference to '__strncpy_chk2'
>     clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>     ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Step one would be using a newer NDK (not sure which you're using, the other person was using r14b which is ancient). It looks like the coverage runtime library was built against a newer version of Android than you're using and so it can't be used usefully in the NDK. If you have the same issue in r17b, it's an NDK bug.

Note that coverage isn't something we really have support for right now, but it's on my todo list: https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/612.